# How to apply style to the divs that are added dynamically?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a view, where kendo framework adds drop downs dynamically through JQuery based on the user clicks. Lets name them drop downs A,B and C.

The div at the page load is something like this

```
<div id="fieldSet">
</div>
```

After user starts clicking these drop down divs starts getting added.

I want to set the style, left position for these drop downs something like for A as 40%, for B 50% and C as 60%.

What type of selector I can use? Since kendo will add drop downs dynamically based on user click. If user clicks for B content type first the content type b will be added first. If a user clicks A, it will be added first. That is the html for it:

```
<div id="fieldSet">
      <div  class ="fieldSetDropDown"> Drop down  A</div>
      <div  class ="fieldSetDropDown"> Drop down B</div>
      <div  class ="fieldSetDropDown"> Drop down C </div> 
</div>
```

So how can I set the left position in this scenario???

**Note**: As I mentioned its getting added through kendo, an external jquery library, I do not have any control on the way it gets added, so i cant modify the html it adds. I am also not allowed to add any jQuery or JavaScript code. I just have permission to add css.

---

**Approach I tried and failed at:**
I tried siblings selectors like

```
#fieldSet .fieldSetDropDown{
left:40%
}

#fieldSet .fieldSetDropDown~ .fieldSetDropDown{
left:50%
}

#fieldSet .fieldSetDropDown~ .fieldSetDropDown ~ .fieldSetDropDown{
left:60%
}
```

This works fine but only if I click the content type in the sequence a, b and c. But if i don't follow the sequence it does not. Suppose If  I click the B drop down first it will be the first div added and it will apply 40% to B. The MAIN problem is that these drop downs have no ID, and just the same class "fieldSetDropDown".

Comment: Maybe you could float them left and add a padding to the #fieldSet container?

Comment: You don't have id specified but if you know that which div is 'A' and which one is 'B', you must be knowing their innerHTML

Comment: Pure css solution seems impossible here. Can you plug some js on drop down display event with Kendo? If so, then try to add ids on the newly created <div class="fieldSetDropDown">

Comment: If you're offsetting them, it would appear that C would be a subset of B, and B would be a subset of A (think Country - Province - County). From what you're saying, this relationship is not actually the case, The contents of C are not controlled by the B selection, and the contents of B are not controlled by the A selection. Are you sure this is the UI situation you want? The indentation would be pretty misleading.

Comment: Yes that its what I want. Lets just suppose its a drop down for countries. One for UK, one for France, and one for Italy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the `nth-child`selector:

```
.fieldSetDropDown:nth-child(1) {
left:40%
}

.fieldSetDropDown:nth-child(2) {
left:50%
}

.fieldSetDropDown:nth-child(3) {
left:60%
}
```

BTW: You have a typo in your HTML: "classs" must be "class"

Comment: But divs are being added dynamically. If div B is added first, would'nt it be the first child. And that's the problem.

Comment: the the only chance to adress them individually is to add them already with an ID or class (which is a JS/jQuery thing).

Comment: I meant somehow adding additional IDs via jQuery when they are created dynamically